# Google Maps api V3 update marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I've got a map that loads.
I want to add a marker that gets it's lat and long from text boxes, and I can't fathom it.

Nothing happens when I click on the updatemap button.

Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Dom, dom dom dom dom");


var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.65, -74);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
}



$("#updateMap").click(function(){


    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    marker.setPosition(newLatLng);

    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('markerLat').value);
    var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('markerLng').value);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);


    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newLatLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });


});


});



// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Update**

Also, your global `map` reference is never set to the actual map instance since you shadow it with a local `var` same name.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
```

This should be just

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
```

---

You're using `lat` and `lng` for the marker position before they're initialized (unless they're globally set somewhere):

```
var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
```

If you want to update the position of the same marker and not create a new one, you should simply be doing this:

```
$("#updateMap").click(function(){
    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('markerLat').value);
    var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('markerLng').value);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First, in `initialize` function you are creating new local `map` variable, because you use `var` keyword. This variable is not visible outside `initialize`, so you need to remove `var` to use global variable.

Second, you are using `lat` and `lng` variables before they are defined.

Third, you are accessing `setPosition` method of `marker` variable when `marker` may not be defined.

After fixing all of these your code may look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Dom, dom dom dom dom");

    var map;
    var marker;

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.65, -74);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    }

    $("#updateMap").click(function(){

    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('markerLat').value);
    var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('markerLng').value);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    if (marker != undefined)
        marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
    else
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newLatLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
    });
    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```